# Passing String from one class to another

Tags: java

How can I pass string variable or String object from one class to another?
I've 2 days on this problem.

One class get data from keyboard and second one should print it in console.

Comment: Sounds like a good question for your classmates or instructor. Your class is also a resource, don't ignore it.

Comment: So what the issue? And where is your code what all you have written in 2 days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. create an instance of your printer class and evoke the method on the printer object:

   ```
   public class MyPrinter
   {
       public void printString( String string )
       {
           System.out.println( string );
       }
   }
   ```

in your main:

```
MyPrinter myPrinter = new MyPrinter();
myPrinter.printString( input );
```

or 2. you create a static method in your printer class and evoke it in your main:

```
public class MyPrinter
{
    public static void printStringWithStaticMethod(String string)
    {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

in your main:

```
MyPrinter.printStringWithStaticMethod( input );
```

Answer (score 4):

Take some help from the below code:-

```
public class ReadFrom {
  private String stringToShow; // String in this class, which other class will read
  public void setStringToShow(String stringToShow) {
    this.stringToShow = stringToShow;
  }

  public String getStringToShow() {
    return this.stringToShow;
  }
}

class ReadIn {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // for taking Keyboard input
    ReadFrom rf = new ReadFrom();
    rf.setStringToShow(sc.nextLine()); // Setting in ReadFrom string
    System.out.println(rf.getStringToShow()); // Reading in this class
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a method inside your second class with `System.out.println(parameter);`
Make the method static and then invoke this in first method like

```
ClassName.methodName(parameter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside class that accepts `Scanner` input

```
variableName ClassName = new Classname();

variablename.methodToPrintString(string);
```

A textbook can always help in this situation.

Comment: thanks for the edit... i was trying to be as vague as possible tho as it sounds like he is in a course attempting to teach him how to do this.